# Linked List in python is not showing the correct results

Tags: python, oop, linked-list

I want my code to print numbers from 0 to 5, instead it prints only 0 as output. Can anyone correct the code.
code:

```
class Node:
  def __init__(self, value):
    self.value = value
    self.next = None

class LinkedList:
  def __init__(self):
    self.head = None
  def display(self):
    ptr = self.head
    while ptr is not None:
      print(ptr.value)
      ptr = ptr.next

l1 = LinkedList()
ptr = l1
ptr.head = Node(0)
ptr.head.next = None
a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

for i in a:
    dummy = Node(i)
    ptr.next = dummy
    ptr = ptr.next

# Displaying the linked list
l1.display()
```

I tried to build a simple linked list in python and was trying to print the numbers that were stored in the linked list, but there is something wrong with my code and it isn't working as I wanted it to be.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  What is the error?   Please post the full traceback error.

Comment: @ewokx OP specifically states, that it only prints 0. There's no error.

Comment: @Cow sorry.. I went by the title of the post which states "causes an error".

Comment: @ewokx Fixed, I can see how that could cause misunderstandings.

Comment: @Cow thanks.  Since I have seen people state an error in the title but didn't include the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already have an answer, but I wanted to point out that you initialised `ptr` as an instance of `LinkedList`, but then in the loop deal with it *as if* it is an instance of `Node`. But as `ptr` is a `LinkedList`, it does not have a `next` attribute, and so the first iteration of the loop is actually *adding* a `next` attribute to the `ptr` object, and the rest of the values are chained to that.

Before the first iteration, we have:

```
 l1  ptr
  ↓   ↓ 
┌─[LinkedList]─┐   ┌─[Node]─────┐
│ head: ──────────►│ value: 0   │
│              │   │ next: None │
└──────────────┘   └────────────┘
```

After the first iteration, we have accidentally created `next` in the linked list instance:

```
 l1 
  ↓ 
┌─[LinkedList]─┐   ┌─[Node]─────┐
│ head: ──────────►│ value: 0   │
│ next: ─┐     │   │ next: None │
└────────│─────┘   └────────────┘
         │ ┌─[Node]─────┐
         └►│ value: 1   │
           │ next: None │
           └────────────┘
             ↑
            ptr
```

And when all iterations have been done:

```
 l1 
  ↓ 
┌─[LinkedList]─┐   ┌─[Node]─────┐
│ head: ──────────►│ value: 0   │
│ next: ─┐     │   │ next: None │
└────────│─────┘   └────────────┘
         │ ┌─[Node]───┐ ┌─[Node]───┐ ┌─[Node]───┐ ┌─[Node]───┐ ┌─[Node]─────┐
         └►│ value: 1 │ │ value: 2 │ │ value: 3 │ │ value: 4 │ │ value: 5   │
           │ next: ────►│ next: ────►│ next: ────►│ next: ────►│ next: None │
           └──────────┘ └──────────┘ └──────────┘ └──────────┘ └────────────┘
                                                                 ↑
                                                                ptr
```

But as the `display` function will (correctly) start from `head` and not from `next`, it will only find the node with value 0.

#### Other Remarks

Methods of your class should not have `print` -- except while debugging. Instead of a `display` method, it is better practice to define a method that returns a string, and leave it to the caller to print it. You could even define the `__repr__` method for this, so that when the caller calls `print` with a linked list as argument, this method will return the string for it.

And we can still improve. We could move the loop from `display` into a method called `__iter__`, so that a linked list is iterable. That feature can then be used for building the string in `__repr__`, but also for other purposes.

Finally, it would be nice if the linked list constructor could already take the values for it as arguments, and insert these values immediately. In the loop that adds these values, you could also consider to do it backwards, while passing the `next` link to the constructor as an extra argument. I find this quite elegant, as you don't have the need for a separate `ptr` variable then.

So all that leads to this code:

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, value, nextnode=None):  # Added parameter
        self.value = value
        self.next = nextnode
    
class LinkedList:
    def __init__(self, *values):  # Allow to immediately populate
        self.head = None
        for value in reversed(values):
            self.insert(value)

    def insert(self, value):
        self.head = Node(value, self.head)

    def __iter__(self):
        ptr = self.head
        while ptr:
            yield ptr.value
            ptr = ptr.next

    def __repr__(self):
        return " ".join(map(str, self))  # Relying on __iter__
    
l1 = LinkedList(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)  # Pass values immediately
print(l1)  # Relying on __repr__
```

Comment: Great analysis, thanks

Answer (score 2):

The issue is because when you initialized `ptr`, and set `ptr.head.next = None`, you didn't move the ptr forward.

Try:

```
class Node:

    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value
        self.next = None

class LinkedList:

    def __init__(self):
        self.head = None

    def display(self):
        ptr = self.head
        while ptr is not None:
            print(ptr.value)
            ptr = ptr.next

l1 = LinkedList()
ptr = l1
ptr.head = Node(0)
ptr.head.next = None
ptr = ptr.head
a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

for i in a:
    dummy = Node(i)
    ptr.next = dummy
    ptr = ptr.next

# Displaying the linked list
l1.display()
```

Running it produces:

```
0
1
2
3
4
5
```